# Equivalence of cauchy problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $P$ and $A$ be linear operator and $F$ a polynomial function.
$$
(1)\qquad \left\{\begin{array}{rcc}
&Pu_t(t) + Au(t)  =  F(u(t)) & t > 0 \\
& u(0)  =  u_0 &
\end{array}\right. 
$$
If $P$ is invertible, then we can consider
$$
(2)\qquad \left\{\begin{array}{rcc}
&u_t(t) + P^{-1}Au(t)  =  P^{-1}F(u(t)) & t > 0 \\
& u(0)  =  u_0 &
\end{array}\right. 
$$
What is the relationship between solutions of $(1)$ and solutions of $(2)$?

*Attempt of solution*: let $u$ be a solution of $(1)$, then $Pu_t(t) = -Au(t) + F(u)$, so that, applying $P^{-1}$, $u_t(t) = -P^{-1}Au(t) + P^{-1}F(u)$. Also $u(0) = u_0$ and this means that $u$ is a solution of $(2)$. The viceversa is similar.

This should mean that $u$ is a solution of $(1)$ if and only if $u$ is a solution of $(2)$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Are you sure your operators are defined everywhere, or just densely defined? $P$, $A$, and $F$ may not have the same domains as $P^{-1}A$ and $P^{-1}F$.

Comment: Nice question +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Here is logical explanation. Consider statements
$$
\small
\begin{align}
A&:\quad Pu_t(t) + Au(t)  =  F(u(t)) \quad t > 0\\
B&:\quad u(t) + P^{-1}Au(t)  =  P^{-1}F(u(t)) \quad t > 0\\
C&:\quad u(0)=u_0
\end{align}
$$
Systems $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent to conjunctions $A\wedge C$ and $A\wedge C$ respectively. Thanks to invertability of $P$, we can say $A\Longleftrightarrow B$. Thus we have
$$
\small
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
Pu_t(t) + Au(t)  =  F(u(t)) & t > 0 \\
 u(0)  =  u_0 &
\end{array}\right.
\Longleftrightarrow
A\wedge C 
\Longleftrightarrow
B\wedge C
\Longleftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
u_t(t) + P^{-1}Au(t)  =  P^{-1}F(u(t)) & t > 0 \\
 u(0)  =  u_0 &
\end{array}\right.
$$